# Using gradient on report body instead of one color?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report and I want to be able to fill in the background such that it's darker at the bottom and gradually gets lighter towards the top.

I know this can be done in the charts but I want to do it on the report itself. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if this is natively possible... You've probably seen yourself when checking the background colour property for the report body that you can't specify a gradient or anything like that. Same for Rectangles. You could maybe specify a background image that has the desired pattern, but who knows how SSRS would render this with all the other report elements.

Comment: Thank you Ian, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is natively possible... You've probably seen yourself when checking the background colour property for the report body that you can't specify a gradient or anything like that, only the colour and that's it - it will be applied uniformly to the entire body. Same for Rectangles.

You could maybe specify a background image that has the desired pattern, but who knows how SSRS would render this with all the other report elements? It might work fine in some circumstances but I imagine it would not work in all renderers.

Unfortunately I just don't think there is a good way to do this, sorry.

Comment: Note, this was originally a comment but I prefer not to just add a "no" answer straight away to try and encourage further answers... However there have been no further suggestions and a few people have agreed with the original comment so adding it as an answer.